# layout doesn't change on mobile screen

Tags: android, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, mobile-browser

Here I have an bootstrap 3 layout and as you can see when I change browser dimension it works well:

[image]

but when I try this on mobile I dont get version with `.xs` clasess I get version with full screen like on normal browser domension screen.

What can be the problem? Bootstrap 3 or my mobile phone browsers?

Comment: Try using Bootstrap's [Bootlint](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/W003) tool next time; it would have caught this omission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, you need to add this to your head.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

To be compatible with 'old' non-responsive websites, most mobile browsers automatically fake their screen to be larger, so that they can correctly display those sites. This meta tag prevents them from doing this.